# Wrong data due to Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I  remove unreal data that I'm getting after several joins that I ran.

my entire Query is:

```
SELECT 
 distinct vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_name

 ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id
 ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.parttype_name
 ,operation_code
 ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name
 ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.qdf_number
      , requestor
      ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_by
      ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_datetime as time1
      ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].distribution_list 
      ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].recipient_name
      , DATEPART(WW,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_datetime) as WW
      ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.product_code_name
      ,task_name
      ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.full_location_name

  FROM [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[vw_public_request_material_location_mir]


         left join request on vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id = request.request_key
        left join vortex_dbo.material_request on vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id = vortex_dbo.material_request.material_request_id
        left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location on vw_public_request_material_location_mir.last_result_id = vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.last_result_id
          left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_history on  vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id like (substring(vw_public_material_history.comments,12,6)) 


  where (vw_public_request_material_location_mir.qdf_number not like 'null' and vw_public_request_material_location_mir.qdf_number  not like '')

  and vw_public_request_material_location_mir.product_code_name like 'LAKE%'

  and vw_public_request_material_location_mir.task_id not like 'null'

  and (vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'bin 100' or  vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'bin 01'
   or  vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'bin 02' or vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'pass')
 and (requestor like 'BUGANIM, RINAT' and employee_name like 'BUGANIM, RINAT')




  and  ( DateDiff(DD,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_datetime, getdate()) < 180)



 and (concat('',substring(vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.comments,12,6)) like vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id


  or vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.comments like 'Changed by Matrix Transaction Handler' or vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.comments like 'Unit Ownership:%')

  and (unit_number = vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_name or unit_number is null)

  and vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_name like 'D7QM748200403'

 order by vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_name desc
```

The results I'm getting are:
two rows that only the 2nd one contains true data.

```
material_name   material_request_id parttype_name   operation_code  result_name qdf_number  requestor   created_by  time1   WW  product_code_name   task_name   full_location_name
D7QM748200403   332160  H6 4GXDCV K Y   7295    BIN 01  Q1T5    BUGANIM, RINAT  SMS_Interface   2017-12-03 20:27:30.327 49  CANNON LAKE Y 2+2   PPV-M   SAMPLE: QDF INVENTORY
D7QM748200403   332176  H6 4GXDCV K Y   7295    BIN 01  Q1T5    BUGANIM, RINAT  SMS_Interface   2017-12-03 21:02:33.247 49  CANNON LAKE Y 2+2   PPV-M   SAMPLE: QDF INVENTORY
```

What can I do in order to retrieve true data only?, I have more cases like this.
Thanks!!

Comment: You should provide sample data. Your formatting is not doing you any favours either.

Comment: What do you mean by sample data? how my db looks like?

Comment: Yes, you have provided an output with two rows, and you suggest that the second row provides true data. But you haven't provided any information about the data in the database that led to that result.

Comment: yes you're right. it because I made several joins in order to retrieve my table. some of them are missing "material_name" data and join multiply them.
if I will send each table data for one unit it may help you to help me?